# display a div based on url parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

My website is [trackschoolbus.com](http://www.trackschoolbus.com/). You can see a login form at the top right. What I have set up is when a wrong input is given it redirects to home page with a parameter as `?er=1` i.e. http://www.trackschoolbus.com/?er=1.
I need to display a error message when the error url comes so I have written

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function(){ 
           if (document.location.href.indexOf('er=1') > 0) 
$("#display").show(); 
   }); 
</script>
```

and the html is

```
<div id="display" style="display:none;">wrong input</div>
```

my login form is

```
<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="http://www.trackschoolbus.com/vehicleTracking/index.php">
    <input name="LoginForm[username]" id="LoginForm_username" type="text" placeholder="Registered Email" value="" class="error" required/>
    <input maxlength="30" name="LoginForm[password]" id="LoginForm_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" class="error" required />
    <input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();" name="yt0" class="btn-submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

still it shows display none.

Comment: Instead of Javascript you can use php condition

Comment: how can i add that  ?

Comment: Is the `$("#display").show(); ` inside `if{ }` or the code formatting is so?

Comment: You have _Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function_ error on this page. What about fixing it?

Comment: `<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();"` is highly questionable. NEVER submit in a submit event and in some cases the submit event is stopped when the button is disabled. Instead hide it or replace it in the FORM's submit event

Comment: @mplungjan - how to do that?

Comment: `$("login-form").on("submit",function() { $("input[name='yt0']").hide();});`

Comment: i have done that for disabling double click and submit

Comment: @mplungjan why is not good in the way i have done?

Comment: Because a) you may interfere in the submission by submitting while submitting. b) some browsers will see you disabled the submit button and will then not submit

Comment: i have tried giving your code but it did not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use php

```
    <form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="http://www.trackschoolbus.com/vehicleTracking/index.php">
            <input name="LoginForm[username]" id="LoginForm_username" type="text" placeholder="Registered Email" value="" class="error" required/>
            <input maxlength="30" name="LoginForm[password]" id="LoginForm_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" class="error" required />
            <input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();" name="yt0" class="btn-submit" value="Login" />
            <?php if (isset($_GET['er']) && $_GET['er'] == 1) {
                echo '<div id="display">wrong input</div>';
            }?>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
if ($_REQUEST['er']==1)
{
   echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $("#display").show(); 
   </script>';
}
```

Comment: It may work, but it's less elegant than just generating the div with PHP (Madalin's solution). Your solution injects a script that shows an existing div, that's two steps instead of one.

Comment: @JeremyThille I think his answer will always make display:none of div

Comment: All the more reason :)

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple in javascript.

Using the code snippet in this thread: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```js
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
if (getParameterByName("er") == "1") 
    $("#display").show(); 
});
```